# How to set container transform animation when using ActivityResultLauncher

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I'm trying to set container transform on a floating action button between activities like the one in this material  [link](https://m3.material.io/libraries/mdc-android/motion#container-transform). According to the material document I'm using AcitivityOptions to set the animation

```
  val options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
            this,
            binding.fabSubmitTicket,
            resources.getString(R.string.fab_shared_element_container)
        )
```

The issue is that I have to use ActivityResultLauncher because startActivityForResult() is deprecated. The code in the material link works fine but when I change

```
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
```

to

```
intent.putExtras(options.toBundle())
activityResultLauncher.launch(intent)
```

the animation doesn't work anymore. Also here is my activityResultLauncher field:

```
private val activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
    handleSubmitTicketResult(it)
}
```

So my question is how could I use container transform along with ActivityResultLauncher?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find an answer. In the ActivityResultLauncher there is an overload launch method that also takes ActivityOptionsCompat as an argument.
[image]

So if type of the options variable is ActivityOptionsCompat instead of ActivityOptions you can use this overload and it would work ok and show the animation properly.

```
val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
            this,
            binding.fabSubmitTicket,
            resources.getString(R.string.fab_shared_element_container)
        )
        
activityResultLauncher.launch(intent, options)
```